# How to use url_path in Google Tag Manager to track directories

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to have content groups in Google Analytics and I'm using Google Tag Manager to implement them. The way to do it, [according to their reference](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/4448540?hl=en), is to create a lookup table that is using the url_path macro to filter URLs. The url_path only gives the path of the URL, stripping the end of it, so for a url http://www.example.com/hello/index.html the result would be /hello/.

I want to group my users' account pages which are like: http://www.example.com/accounts/profile/user1/

The problem with the above macro is that it would return /accounts/profile/user1 which is not what I want. I only want to keep /accounts/profile/.

How could I accomplish that using this macro?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create the content groups in GA directly by using extractions or, even simpler, rules ("page contains profile") ?

Comment: Good point, it's what I tried at first but it doesn't seem to work. I'm using Google Analytics Debug extension in Chrome and when I test this implementation it doesn't work. When the content group is set successfully I can see it passed as a parameter to GA, in the console of the browser. Maybe it doesn't work because GA is being called through GTM.

Comment: Content Groups with GTM should work fine (if you remember to set them up in the GA Backend first) - I'm using that without problems. For me it took quite some time (48 hours) until data for Content Groups first showed up, might that be the issue?

Comment: I will try again then and wait even more time. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Do you have to do anything in GTM except create the GA tag?

Answer (score 0):

For helping you, in GTM you just have to configure the "Content Grouping" part (and take special care of the index that you put in). All the stuff is on GA Backend, where you declare your content group and which give you an index for each content group (index that you have to keep in GTM).
For some GA account you have to wait around 48 hours till you got some data, if your hit is ok you can see your content grouping information in the variable utmpg (like :" 1:Accueil,2:Page de destination | Actualité | ---,5:www.ouest-france.fr/home" for example).

Hopes it will help you to understand.
Fanny